# overflow-y not working with media queries

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I'm trying to remove scroll for desktop, but keep scrolling for mobiles and tablets. Can anyone tell me why the below code does not work?

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    body { 
    overflow-y:visible;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    body { 
    overflow-y:visible;
    }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    body { 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide the html or create a fiddle for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know your media query break points, why not just do your media queries in PX instead like this http://jsfiddle.net/96q3u6ne/

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px){
    body { 
    overflow-y:visible;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body { 
    overflow-y:visible;
    }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body { 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    }
}
```